# Best practice for Wordpress media image use

Tags: images

I'm considering using my company's Wordpress website as a place to upload images (to media) and use the WP URL to link images on the company's email signature.

Mainly so I have a URL to use on the email template for images that are too large to embed on the signature management software we use.

I have reservations as I don't really think it's good practice, which is why I'd like to get other thoughts on the below please?

a) The image will not be used on the website at all, so should it be placed there really?

b) Our company has a lot of email traffic, and we run regular batch sends for invoices/statements etc. Therefore could it slow the website down?

c) Are there security issues doing this?

d) Any other reasons for/against this?!

TIA